# Select data from a temp table using java

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures

I have a SQL stored procedure which select some data and insert to a temp table.

```
    DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE ([record_Id] [int] NOT NULL)
    WHILE(@count>0)
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO @tmpTable
            SELECT top 1 [record_Id] 
            FROM Table1 
        END
   select * from   @tmpTable
```

I used the following code to access the procedure

```
 ResultSet rs=null;Statement stmt=null;
 String getFirstRec="EXEC prod1";
 stmt=con.createStatement();
 rs=stmt.executeQuery(getFirstRec);
```

When I run this it gives me an error saying " the statement did not return the result set". can anyone help me to resolve this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use prepareCall()  for calling procedures

Have a look at here [link](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-out-parameter-example/)

The above link clearly describes how to use procedures

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a [`CallableStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) which can be initialised from your connection using [`prepareCall()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareCall%28java.lang.String%29)

Then use

```
CallableStatement callStat = con.prepareCall("EXEC prod1");
rs = callStat.executeQuery();
```